# How to access a field of another model in a button with the attrs attribute?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

How do i access the field `product_id.product_tmpl_id.type` from the `sale.order.line` model.

I have the following button in the xml view:

```
button name="print_report" string="Print" type="object" icon="gtk-print" attrs="{'invisible':[('product_id.product_tmpl_id.type', '!=', 'product')]}"/>.
```

With this statement , Odoo shows me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Campo desconocido product_id.product_tmpl_id.type en el dominio [["product_id.product_tmpl_id.type","!=","product"]]
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that field product_id is declared into the view of the button?
If so, and did not work yet, then you can try to create a related field into sale.order.line

```
type = fields.Selection(related='product_id.product_tmpl_id.type')
```

and use it into domain

```
[('type', '!=', 'product')]
```

(remember to put type field, even invisible, inside the view)